# How to transform the data based on the column name

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transform my `df` where some of the column names are melted in wide-to-long form.

My `df` looks like this:

```
id, university, # CA Holiday, # CA Hours, # WA Holiday, # WA Hours
1    abc              1           5           NA           3
2    def              5           NA           3           7
3    ijk              1           5           NA           3
```

here,

- My keys are: `[id, university]`. The Keys are not melted.
- Output variables: `WA, CA`. Output variables are basically the short-form of the columns, which is broken down.

My final transformed output `df` is arranged like this.

```
id, university, Holiday_State, Holiday, Hours
1    abc          CA           1         5
1    abc          WA          NA         3 
2    def          CA           5         NA
2    def          WA           3         7    
3    ijk          CA           1         5
3    ijk          WA          NA         3
```

Could someone please provide assistance to help solve this problem?

Comment: can you share the data as a dictionary? makes it easier to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

One option is to swap the *prefix/suffix* in order to make *stubnames* for the [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) reshape :

```
out = (df.set_index(["id", "university"])
         .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis([f"{c2}_{c1}"
               for _,c1,c2 in x.columns.str.split(r"\s|_")], axis=1)).reset_index()
         .pipe(pd.wide_to_long, stubnames=["Holiday", "Hours"],
                  i=["id", "university"], j="Holiday_State", sep="_", suffix=r"\w+")
         .reset_index()
      )
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)
           
   id university Holiday_State  Holiday  Hours
0   1        abc            CA     1.00   5.00
1   1        abc            WA      NaN   3.00
2   2        def            CA     5.00    NaN
3   2        def            WA     3.00   7.00
4   3        ijk            CA     1.00   5.00
5   3        ijk            WA      NaN   3.00
```

Comment: Thanks for composing the possible solution. Is it possible to not hard code the '_' part? I updated the column names. Could you please check?

Comment: The column names are a bit ambiguous in your new version. Do you have literal `,` and `#` ?

Comment: Anyways, I updated the answer to handle the case where `list(df.columns)` gives `['id', 'university', '# CA Holiday', '# CA Hours', '# WA_Holiday', '# WA Hours']`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = ['id', 'university'], 
                names_to = ['Holiday_State', '.value'], 
                names_pattern = r".\s([a-zA-Z]+).(.+)",
                sort_by_appearance = True)
   id university Holiday_State  Holiday  Hours
0   1        abc            CA      1.0    5.0
1   1        abc            WA      NaN    3.0
2   2        def            CA      5.0    NaN
3   2        def            WA      3.0    7.0
4   3        ijk            CA      1.0    5.0
5   3        ijk            WA      NaN    3.0
```